# android listview rounded corners

Tags: android, android-listview

i try to create  rounded corners listview.i created custom xml file and i wrote this code

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/shape_my" >

<stroke
    android:width="2dp"
    android:color="#636161" />

<padding
    android:bottom="5dp"
    android:left="5dp"
    android:right="5dp"
    android:top="5dp" />

<corners android:radius="24dp" />

<solid android:color="#FFF" />
```

[my listview looks same as a picture](http://postimg.org/image/als5uve8j/d9fa167e/)

[but i want to recive like this style listview](http://postimg.org/image/i7bg0la1h/ed3d06c6/)

this is a my custom listview adapter code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
android:orientation="horizontal"
>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/cat_image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/cat_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/cat_image"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textColor="#9577a9" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="19dp"
    android:background="@drawable/cat_next" />
```

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/cat_listview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" >
</ListView>
```

how i can solve my problem? if anyone knows solution please help me
thanks

Comment: I don't see where you are using this shape.  It should be set as a background of your list view

Comment: [Check this](http://blog.synyx.de/2011/11/android-listview-with-rounded-corners/). In that middle entries use different style, so only first and last rows are applied top and bottom round corners respectively. This might help you achieve what you need.

Comment: set ListView's background to list_selector and remove background from Relative Layout.

Comment: I think you've posted not your custom listview adapter, but just xml file for the item in that list view. Please, add custom listview adapter code, because the solution of your problem lies there.

Comment: don't apply shape on list item but apply on layout

Answer (score 3):

Check [this](http://blog.synyx.de/2011/11/android-listview-with-rounded-corners/). In that middle entries use different style, so only first and last rows are applied top and bottom round corners respectively. This might help you achieve what you need.

So what you will need to do is:

Simply apply your rounded corner style xml if the item position is first or last.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    //...     

    if (position == 0 && entry_list.size() == 1) {
        view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selector_rounded_corner);
    } else if (position == 0) {
        view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selector_rounded_corner_top);
    } else if (position == entry_list.size() - 1) {
        view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selector_rounded_corner_bottom);
    } else {
        view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selector_middle);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

replace your

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/cat_listview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" >
</ListView>
```

via

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/cat_listview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:background="@drawable/customshape"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" >
</ListView>
```

Comment: and what kind of image would be  customshape?

Comment: that is you <shape> file name